# Episerver FIND result not in CMS

Tags: find, episerver

Sometimes when the user is deleting the page it is not being removed from FIND index. While we are trying to find the issue we want to check if the FIND result is actually there.

For example, on the home page there are news which are coming from FIND. When the user clicks on a news and if the news is not in the CMS they are getting 404.

Is there a way in FIND query to check if the result gotten actually is in CMS. My query is as follows

```cs
SearchResults<ContentReference> result = query
                    .FilterForVisitor()
                    .InLanguageBranch(languageBranch)
                    .OrderByDescending(z => z.Changed)
                    .Take(count)
                    .Select(z => z.ContentLink)
                    .GetResult();
var items = contentLoader.GetItems(result.Hits.Select(x => x.Document), new LanguageSelector(languageBranch)).ToList().Cast<T>();
return items;
```

Comment: When deleting, do you also empty the trashbin in epi?

Comment: Yes I do. Most of the time it works fine. It could be an issue because we have 4 servers but we are trying to find the root cause of the issue

Comment: Side note: you should be able to remove `InLanguageBranch`, as that filter is effectively included in the `FilterForVisitor` filter.

Comment: Also curious: does applying the `ExcludeDeleted` filter yield any different result?